# Is there a way to run an ex command without hitting colon first?

Tags: vimscript, tmux

I am doing some scripting related to tmux and Vim.   In my tmux window, I have Vim in one tmux pane and a Tcl command line in another tmux pane.

I want to create a Tcl proc which will dump a string to /tmp/file and then use `tmux send-keys` to send `:read /tmp/file` to the Vim pane.  This is a way for the results of Tcl commands to be automatically read into my Vim buffer.

This is working fine except that I use normal mode Vim mappings where I swap the colon `:` and the semi-colon `;`.   This means that I actually want `tmux send-keys` to send `;read /tmp/file`.

My colon/semi-colon swap means that whatever I write won't work for someone who doesn't swap colon/semi-colon.

Is it possible for an external program to discover if a open Vim window has remapped the `:` key?  or run an Ex command without preceding it with a colon?

Comment: I… can't think of any way to do this that doesn't involve colon (`:execute "normal! : …\<CR>"`, `:call feedkeys(': …', 'n')`, etc.). The only solution _might_ be the magic key `<cmd>`, but you would be dependent on the internal representation of such a key.

Comment: Possible hacks: `gQ`, commands, `:visual`. Or `q:` to open the command-line window.

Comment: There might be something in the client/server or jobs API that could help

Comment: The `gQ` hack would do the trick.   Thanks!

Comment: Feel free to self-answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ex commands can be executed in Ex mode.   The `Q` key in Normal mode enters Ex mode, but this is often mapped to a no-operation by users to avoid Ex mode entirely.  In fact, `$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim` now remaps `Q` to `gq`.

But Vim being Vim, there's yet another way to enter Ex mode.   `gQ` will enter Ex mode and will update the buffer after each command.

My Tcl proc can now include this code to tell Vim in another tmux pane to read a tmp file:

```
    set keys "gQread $tmp_file"
    lappend keys "C-m"
    lappend keys "visual" "C-m"

    exec tmux send-keys -t $target {*}$keys
```